# How to sum all combinations of rows in Matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm looking to sum all possible combinations of rows in a matrix. A function similar to `rowSums()` function but instead of producing `nrow()`sums, it would produce `nrow() ^ nrow()` sums.

For example:

```
set.seed(10)
dummymat <-  matrix(floor(runif(9, 0, 2)), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

produces the matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

To find every possible row-sum of the matrix, the following very inefficient code could be written:

```
allrowsums <- c()

for(i in 1:nrow(dummymat)) {
  firstcolval <- dummymat[i,1]
  for(j in 1:nrow(dummymat)) {
    secondcolval <- dummymat[j,2]
    for(k in 1:nrow(dummymat)) {
      thirdcolval <- dummymat[k,3]
      rowsum <- firstcolval + secondcolval + thirdcolval
      allrowsums <- append(allrowsums,rowsum)
  }
 }
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
[1] 2 2 3 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

What more-succinct code could I write for much larger matrices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid` to create a data frame of all combinations of column-wise elements.

```
dummymat_expand <- expand.grid(x=dummymat[,1], y=dummymat[,2], z=dummymat[,3])
```

From here, you can just call rowSums to get all possible sum combinations.

```
rowSums(dummymat_expand)
```

Edited to answer question. To apply code to matrices with variable column length, note that `expand.grid` can take vectors, factors or a list as inputs.  You can therefore create a list of column elements to feed to `expand.grid`

```
# create a list of column elements
dummymat_column_list <- lapply(1:ncol(dummymat), function(x) dummymat[, x])
expand.grid(dummymat_column_list)
```

Comment: thanks for this @Djork, can you think how to make the answer dynamic, such that it can handle a matrix of any column length? (And the code doesn't need to be adjusted each time). For a matrix of 100 columns, the code for this answer will also get quite lengthy.

Comment: I edited the answer to address your question.  If this works for you please accept the answer to mark it close.

Comment: thanks @Djork, sorry to be a PITA, but this solution can't deal with larger matrices due to it seems memory consumption. Try for instance `dummymat <-  matrix(floor(runif(5000, 0, 2)), nrow = 1000, ncol = 5)`

Comment: @WillT-E, with 1000 rows, the result would have length 1000^1000, or about 10^3000. Estimates of the number of atoms in the universe are about 10^80. So yes, you'll have some memory issues. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: yes @Gregor that's a very valid point, clearly I hadn't properly thought the potential output through. I'm simulating 5 independent events (one event equals one column) and then adding them together to determine a final 'score'. If I simulate each event 1000 times (which can take a while) and then add each row together, I get 1000 data points (or scores). I was thinking I could lower the number of simulations, but then add all row combinations together, to get more data points in less time without hopefully biasing my results too much (towards the now lower number of simulations).

Comment: Pick a reasonable number of combinations, and instead of trying to do *every* combination, randomly sample that many combos. If you want to be fancy, do them in batches, say 500k at a time, and make a few diagnostic plots in between each batch. My guess is pretty quickly you'll have convergence in the sense that it'll look pretty much the same whether you add more batches or not.